# Mongodb server version 6.0.3 connection Error with pymongo python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have mongodb server version 6.0.3 and PyMongo 3.4.0 version. One thing I know is version mismatch error. But I am not sure which pymongo version will support monogdb 6.0.3 version.

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\first_test_yasir\first_test\surge_shadow_system_elt.py", line 45, in <module>
    for data in extract():
  File "D:\pythonProject\first_test_yasir\first_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1114, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "D:\pythonProject\first_test_yasir\first_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1025, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(_Query(self.__query_flags,
  File "D:\pythonProject\first_test_yasir\first_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 928, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(doc['data'][0])
  File "D:\pythonProject\first_test_yasir\first_test\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: find. The client driver may require an upgrade.
```

I have install different version of pymongo 4.6.0, 4.1.0 etc..

Comment: Are you sure 4.6 doesn't work? What's the specific error that you get with it? [Compatibility matrix](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/pymongo/#compatibility-table-legend) suggests that it should

Comment: Got this error with 4.6 version

raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: xxxx.xxxx.xx.xx.com:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
@user20042973

Comment: Perhaps if you show the code (edit your question) where you connect and also where the error(s) occur, more help could be provided.